# Scene ran fine, then updated windows, now playback is VERY slow

Tags: animation, performance, windows

So, I was animating a scene, not too complex, and playback was fine, then I found out my windows was outdated so I clicked update and restart, it then took 5 attempts to get back into the computer as the CPU would malfunction, and when I did, the same scene(no changes) couldn't even get past 18 fps.  Nothing I've tried works, I updated my graphics drivers and everything.

**System Specs:**
Ryzen 5 1600
16GB Ram(2400)
GTX 1070(non-ti variant)
MSI B350M PRO-VDH Motherboard
Stock Cooler
EVGA 80+ Gold Supernova G2 850W PSU
1TB WD Red Pro Hard Drive(7200 rpm 64MB Cache)

Does anyone have a clue as to what happened and more importantly, how to fix it?

P.S. All other cases of this happening were because of an underpowered system.  This time, it was working fine and now it isn't.

Comment: Every time windows updates itself, besides the colosal waste of time involved in the process, some of the drivers break. Try to update the drivers for your hardware to a current version.

Comment: This last Windows update was the last straw for me... same problem.. but I was lucky: mine was fixed by driver reinstall.. I'm now engaged in the research to return to where I started: Unix... well... nowadays... Linux.

Comment: I tried it, it didn't seem to fix the issue.